# ffmpeg questions

Tags: c++, mfc, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I have a problem with ffmpeg and I don't know how to continue. I have 2 computers:

**Client :**

- Run Ubuntu 14.04
- FFmpeg installed
- Use c++ language
- Features: use ffmpeg to encode h264 video data from webcam of client laptop, then real time streaming to server

**Server:**

- Running Windows 7
- FFmpeg installed
- Use c++ language (MFC)
- Features: Get real time data from client and show it on screen.

I've just connected client to server and they can chat text data together, and I don't have any idea to make real time video work.

And my questions are:

1. [Client] How to get video from webcam on laptop (using ffmpeg code), save it to buffer (raw data), encode it and send to server?

   I use ffmpeg to get video from wc but it save to file. I really don't want it. Code is:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
   ```
2. [Client] How to get raw data from client, decode it and play it?

   I have an idea to play it by using directshow in MFC.

Comment: What are you trying to get to update in real time? What have you tried to get it to update in real time?

Comment: I am trying to get video from client and show it on server.

Comment: You will need to post what you have attempted in in order to receive help on Stack Overflow, questions that are essentially "tell me how to do this" without showing that you have attempted solutions are not received well on SO.

Comment: a) Change "client" to "server" and vice-versa. b) Use VLC.

Comment: @deviantfan:  "vice-versa" what is that mean? T_T My project is required ffmpeg.

Comment: @QuestionGuy http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vice+versa

Comment: @DrCord: i have just edit my question more clear. Is that ok? Thank u.

Comment: @deviantfan: ah ah. Just my way to call. Thank u. Do u have an idea for my question? Im so confuse...

Comment: That's much better, I think you are much more likely to get help! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you must you could implement your own player in c++ using the [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) libraries or the [libav](https://libav.org/download.html) libraries. This allows you to support a wide range of codecs and formats.

On Windows you can use the c++ [Windows Media Player Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563023(v=vs.85).aspx), but it supports only a few formats, and no H.264.

You have the following options on the origin server (your Linux box):

- `vlc` transcode

DivX3 with MP3 in ASF seem to be accepted by WMP:

```
cvlc input.mp4 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=DIV3,scale=Auto,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=asf,dst=:8080/}" --sout-keep
```

On the client you can retrieve the stream using `http://server_address:8080`.

- `ffmpeg` with `ffserver`

Read the [ffserver Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) and [Streaming media with ffserver](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver) in order to set it up.

For WMP you'll be using once again ASF:

```
# ASF compatible

<Stream test.asf>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format asf
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 352x240
VideoBitRate 256
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 30
AudioBitRate 64
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

[Source](https://www.ffmpeg.org/sample.html).

You can retrieve the stream using `http://ffserver_address:port/stream_name.asf`.

Comment: Why mention the fork Libav? If you're suggesting that the libraries can be used, then perhaps you mean the FFmpeg libav* libraries?

Comment: I'm aware of the feud. I also know they put a lot of effort in cleaning up the code base and tend to be more focused so I intuitively recommended it to someone who seems to be just starting in this direction. But you're right, I'll update the answer to mention both since it's only fair.